# renaming text files with user-acquired input in python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, variables, user-input

I've been trying to make a function that takes user input, and renames a text file with that string. I've tried `open("%x.txt" % name, "w")`, and `os.rename`. Is there a more effective way I don't know about?

```
import os, sys, time

def textfile():
   f = open("old.txt", "w")
   x = input("name for your file: ")
   os.rename("old.txt", "%x.txt)
   f.write("This is a sentence")
   f.close()

textfile()
```

Comment: More effective, as in faster?

Comment: No, sorry, as in "working". It ends up renaming the file "%x.txt" which was obviously not the goal

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to actually format the string.

```
import os, sys, time

def textfile():
   f = open("old.txt", "w")
   x = input("name for your file: ")
   os.rename("old.txt", "{}.txt".format(x))
   f.write("This is a sentence")
   f.close()

textfile()
```

Comment: Thank you, It should have occured to me that that's how you format the string. I just got back to python after learning HTML5, js, css, ect. so this was a big help.

Comment: You should use the `str.format` method in the long run. It has a lot more to offer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to open a file to rename it. As pointed out by @Bryan Oakely, `os.rename` is the way to do it in Python. Example:

```
s = "old_name.txt"
x = input("name for your file: ")
os.rename(s,x+".txt")
```

will rename `"old_name.txt"` to whatever `x` is (specified by the user) with `.txt` as suffix.

Answer (score 0):

A good way in order to avoid using `input()` is:

```
import os, sys, time

def textfile():
   x = raw_input("name for your file: ")
   os.rename("old.txt", x + ".txt)

textfile()
```

Here you have a security problem since you do not limit the input. A user can add `../hello.txt` and have the file written in another folder. Or even do `/etc/passwd` and have the file written somewhere you probably don't want to.

Comment: `input` in python3 is different, it just returns strings.

Comment: You are right. I did not see it was using Python 3. I will edit my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
import os

def file_rename():
    oldname=input("Old name: ") #Get the old file name, don't forget the extention
    newname=input("New name: ") #Get the new file name (excluding the extention)
    os.rename(oldname,newname + ".txt") #Renames the file

file_rename() #Calls the function above
```

This should be fine if you'd like to rename different files in the same directory however, if not just set the oldname input to a string such as "example.txt".